# Spring boot Resource Not Found 404 error html

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web

I built a crud application called Employer. Operations are working fine however when it comes to display them in html console shows error Not Found

```
: Resource not found
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2019-07-29 05:04:25.834 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Mon Jul 29 05:04:25 PDT 2019, status=404, error=Not Found, message=No message available,  (truncated)...]
2019-07-29 05:04:25.835 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
2019-07-29 05:04:37.741 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/favicon.ico", parameters={}
2019-07-29 05:04:37.742 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/], class path resource []]
2019-07-29 05:04:37.754 DEBUG 18656 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

I tried to restart the app and change the name of Entity,but it didnt work.Below are what I tried

EmployerController.java

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.hibernate.mapping.Index;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@Controller
public class EmployerController {


    @Autowired
    private EmployerService service;




    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String newForm() {
        return "form1";
    }






     public List<Employer>getAllEmployers()
     {


        return  service.getAllEmployers();



     }

        @RequestMapping(value="/tables",method=RequestMethod.GET)

    public String getAllEmployers(Model model)
    {
         List<Employer>employers = service.getAllEmployers(); 
        model.addAttribute("Employer",employers);
        return "tables";
    }





      @RequestMapping("/employer/{id}") 
      public Employer getEmployer(@PathVariable Integer id) { 
          return service.getEmployers(id);
      }



    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value="/employer")
    public void addEmployer(@RequestBody Employer employer) {
        service.addEmployer(employer);

    }


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT,value="/employer/{id}")
    public void updateEmployer(@RequestBody Employer employer,@PathVariable int id) {
        service.updateEmployer(id,employer);
    }




      @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE,value="/create/{id}") 
     public void deleteEmployer(@PathVariable int id)
     {
          service.deleteEmployer(id);
     }




}
```

EmployerService.java

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@Service
public class EmployerService {
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    public List<Employer>getAllEmployers(){
        List<Employer>employers = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll()
        .forEach(employers::add);
        return employers;

    }

    public void addEmployer(Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }


    public void updateEmployer(int id, Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }


    public void deleteEmployer(int id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
        ;
    }



      public Employer getEmployers(int id) 
      { 
          return repository.getOne(id);

      }





}
```

Employer.Java

```
package io.javabrains;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.javabrains.Entity.Employer;

@Service
public class EmployerService {
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    public List<Employer>getAllEmployers(){
        List<Employer>employers = new ArrayList<>();
        repository.findAll()
        .forEach(employers::add);
        return employers;

    }

    public void addEmployer(Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }


    public void updateEmployer(int id, Employer employer) {
        repository.save(employer);
    }


    public void deleteEmployer(int id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
        ;
    }



      public Employer getEmployers(int id) 
      { 
          return repository.getOne(id);

      }





}
```

table.html

```
 <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="$(employers)">
                      <td th:text="${employers.name}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${employer.position}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${employer.office}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${employer.age}"></td>
                     <td th:text="${employer.salary}"></td>
                    </tr>
```

....

Comment: Would you try replacing `@Controller` by `@RestController`?

Comment: Yes I tried to replace restController to Controller because RestController restricts the access to template and always returns String

Comment: As I have mentioned in the answer, if you want to continue with `@Controller `add `@ResponseBody` annotation as well along with `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: if I add @ResponseBody along with RequestMapping, controllers keeps returning the String as always

Comment: can you also post your pom.xml (Maven) or build.gradle (Gradle) in the question? I would like to see dependencies injected. Which template engine you are using?

Comment: the return string should match with name of the file. e.g it should be tables.html

Comment: The error message that you see is because of there is no mapping for /error endpoint

Comment: add error.html in your src/main/resources/templates/

Comment: fiveelements yes I will post here

Comment: <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
<artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: btw,the problem is not its getting an error, the problem is it can not find the resource which is coming from database?

Comment: @Alex see my updated answer. You may try all three options I have used in my controller:  `public ModelAndView getHelloTemplate()`, `public String getHelloTemplate(Model model)`, `public String getHelloTemplate(ModelMap model)`. Add this dependency in pom.xml: `org.springframework.boot::spring-boot-starter-freemarker`. If this works then your issue is very specific to Thymeleaf like view resolver is not configured etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `@Controller` (`org.springframework.stereotype.Controller`) in your controller class you also have to add `@ResponseBody` for each `@RequestMapping` or at the class level.

Alternatively, Spring has introduced `@RestController` (`org.springframework.stereotype.Controller.RestController`) that includes both `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.

Also, in the API can you try the following, I have tested now and it works.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/template")
public ModelAndView getHelloTemplate(){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.setViewName("hello");
    model.addObject("message", "Hello World");
    return model;
}
```

I have used `spring-boot-starter-freemarker` template engine and the the html file is placed under `src/main/resources/templates/hello.ftl'.

Now, I have tested the same code with Thymeleaf and it works.

**pom.xml:**

```
<!--<dependency>-->
<!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>-->
<!--<version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--</dependency>-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller(value = "tvGuideController")
public class TvGuideController {
    @RequestMapping(path="/template")
    public ModelAndView getHelloTemplate(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("hello");
        model.addObject("message", "Hello World");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/template1")
    public String getHelloTemplate(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World 1");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/template2")
    public String getHelloTemplate(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World 2");
        return "hello2";
    }
}
```

The running application with both Thymeleaf and Freemarker template engines are available [at github](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference)
Clone the repository and run the application:

```
git clone https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference.git
cd java/springboot
mvn spring-boot:run
```

URLs (port may be different for you):

```
http://localhost:8080/template
http://localhost:8080/template1
http://localhost:8080/template2
```

If you want to run freemarker instead of thymeleaf in pom.xml comment out thymeleaf dependency and uncomment freemarker dependency.

If this works for you then, certainly your pom.xml dependencies, application.properties, main Application class and the Controller need to be checked.